# Simple way to modify deeply nested struct

Tags: swift

I've been becoming more familiar with the "copy on write" behavior of Swift structs. I think it's a really nice way to get around having to manage references for structs, but it's a bit cumbersome when dealing with deeply nested structures.

If you want to update a deeply nested value, you need a direct path to that value so you can modify it on a single line:

```swift
myStruct.nestedArray[index].nestedValue = 1
```

The compiler will copy `myStruct.nestedArray[index]` and set `nestedValue` to `1` on that new value. It will then copy `myStruct.nestedArray` and set the new value at `index`. It will then copy `myStruct` and replace the previous value with a new one that has all of the above changes.

This works just fine and it's pretty cool that you can do this with a single line of code without having to worry about anything that was referencing `myStruct` and its children before. However, if there is more complicated logic involved in resolving the path to the value, the logic becomes much more verbose:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    var nestedEnum: MyEnum
}

enum MyEnum {
    case one([NestedStruct])
    case two([NestedStruct])
}

struct NestedStruct {
    var id: Int
    var nestedValue: Int
}

var myStruct = MyStruct(nestedEnum: .one([NestedStruct(id: 0, nestedValue: 0)]))
if case .one(var nestedArray) = myStruct.nestedEnum {
    if let index = nestedArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == 0 }) {
        nestedArray[index].nestedValue = 1
        myStruct.nestedEnum = .one(nestedArray)
    }
}
```

Ideally you'd be able to do something like this:

```swift
if case .one(var nestedArray) = myStruct.nestedEnum {
    if var nestedStruct = nestedArray.first(where: { $0.id == 0 }) {
        nestedStruct.nestedValue = 1
    }
}
```

But as soon as `nestedStruct.nestedValue` is set, the new value of `nestedStruct` is swallowed.

What would be nice is if Swift had a way to use `inout` semantics outside of functions, so I could take a "reference" to `nestedArray` and then `nestedStruct` within it and set the inner `nestedValue`, causing the copy to propagate back up to `myStruct` the same way as it would if I'd been able to do it in one line.

Does anyone have any nice ways to deal with deeply nested structs that might be able to help me out here? Or am I just going to have to put up with the pattern from my second example above?

Comment: Sounds like you need a class... The long way you showed _is_ how you mutate deeply nested structs. If you don't like that, use a class. From my experience, structs work best when they are immutable.

Comment: Unfortunately this is being used for SwiftUI, so the values work best as structs. I actually found a nice way to deal with deeply nested stuff using `Binding`s. The pattern aligns nicely with SwiftUI's hierarchical structure.

Comment: @jchitel can you please provide mode details on your findings?

Comment: @VikasDadheech I just posted an answer with the solution I used.

Comment: @jchitel The behavior you described had nothing to with copy-on-write. It's due to value copy in statement like `if var nestedStruct = ...`. In types like array, dict, etc., the general approach to achieve what you'd like to have is to use index (or key in dict case) to modify the nested part directly. In your example, however, there is another thing to consider: it's impossible to do in-place modification of enum associated values (see a discussion at https://forums.swift.org/t/in-place-mutation-of-an-enum-associated-value/11747)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up arriving at was pretty SwiftUI specific, but it may be adaptable to other frameworks.

Basically, instead of having a single top-level method responsible for deeply updating the struct, I arranged my SwiftUI hierarchy to mirror the structure of my struct, and passed `Binding`s down that just manage one node of the hierarchy.

For example, given my struct defined above:

```swift
struct MyStruct {
    var nestedEnum: MyEnum
}

enum MyEnum {
    case one([NestedStruct])
    case two([NestedStruct])
}

struct NestedStruct {
    var id: Int
    var nestedValue: Int
}
```

I could do this:

```swift
struct MyStructView: View {
    @Binding var myStruct: MyStruct

    var body: some View {
        switch myStruct.nestedEnum {
        case .one: OneView(array: oneBinding)
        case .two: TwoView(array: twoBinding)
        }
    }

    var oneBinding: Binding<[NestedStruct]> {
        .init(
            get: {
                if case .one(array) = myStruct.nestedEnum {
                     return array
                }
                fatalError()
            },
            set: { myStruct.nestedEnum = .one($0) }
        )
    }

    var twoBinding: Binding<[NestedStruct]> { /* basically the same */ }
}

struct OneView: View {
    @Binding var array: [NestedStruct]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<array.count, id: \.self) {
            NestedStructView(nestedStruct: getBinding($0))
        }
    }

    func getBinding(_ index: Int) -> Binding<NestedStruct> {
        .init(get: { array[index] }, set: { array[index] = $0 })
    }
}

struct NestedStructView: View {
    @Binding var nestedStruct: NestedStruct

    var body: some View {
        NumericInput(title: "ID: \(nestedStruct.id)", value: valueBinding)
    }

    var valueBinding: Binding<Int> {
        .init(get: { nestedStruct.value }, set: { nestedStruct.value = $0 })
    }
}
```

The only annoying bit is that it can be a bit verbose to construct a `Binding` manually. I wish SwiftUI had some syntax for getting nested `Binding`s from a `Binding` containing an array or struct.